# floating left issue

Tags: css, layout, css-float

Again I have some issues with float:left property.
I have three divs. I want to float "holder" to left side of the first div, but it doest work with my code.

This is my code:
HTML

```
<div id="investments">
   <div class="visual_text_holder"><p>co</p><p>re</p></div>

   <div id="holder">
       <h4>SOMETHING</h4>
   </div>

   <div class="visual_text_holder"><p>id</p><p>ea</p></div>


</div>
```

AND CSS:

```
#investments{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:40px;
    width: 910px;
}

.visual_text_holder {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size:7.5em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height:60%;
    width:140px;
}
#investments:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    visibility: invisible;
    clear: both;
}
#holder {
    width:700px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope this will help You.

JS FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ZWLP/

HTML:

```
<div id="investments">
   <div class="visual_text_holder"><p>co</p><p>re</p></div>

    <div class="holder">
        <h4>SOMETHING</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="clearer" ></div>

    <div class="visual_text_holder"><p>id</p><p>ea</p></div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
#investments{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:40px;
    width: 910px;
}

.visual_text_holder{
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    font-size:7.5em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    line-height:60%;
    width:140px;
    float:left;
}

.holder{
    width:700px;
    float:left;
}

.clearer{
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.visual_text_holder { display: inline-block }
```

Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/float

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container, where text and inline elements will wrap around it.

Thus, block elements (as <div> is by default) will not wrap around a `float`.

Answer (score 0):

FOR WITHOU CHANGING IN HTML CODE CHANGES AS BELOW IN CSS

```
.visual_text_holder {
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size:7.5em;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  line-height:60%;
  width:140px; float:right;
}
#holder {
  width:615px;
  float:left;
}
```

FOR MAKE DIV IN QUE WISE LIKE ( first somting, second co re, third id ea)
    .visual_text_holder {
      font-family: "Times New Roman";
      font-size:7.5em;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      line-height:60%;
      width:140px; float:right;
    }
    #holder {
      width:615px;
      float:left;
    }

```
<div id="investments">
<div class="visual_text_holder"><p>id</p><p>ea</p></div>
<div class="visual_text_holder"><p>co</p><p>re</p></div>

<div id="holder">
<h4>SOMETHING</h4>
```